# 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'default_response_class'

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to include a router in the main FastAPI router:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from test.main.app.google_calendar_wrapper import app as calendar_manager_router

app = FastAPI()

# 
app.include_router(calendar_manager_router, prefix="/calendar_manager", tags=["calendar_manager"])

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Home Page"}
```

However, when running

```
uvicorn  test.main.app.webhook.router:app --port 8050 --reload
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'default_response_class'

My file structure is:

```
test
| main
  | app
    |  google_calendar_wrapper
      | endpoints.py
      | __init__.py
    |  webhooks
      |  router.py
```

So far I have tried:

- Not including the router, in this case the application starts normally
- `google_calendar_wrapper` with and without `__init__.py`. If with an `__init__.py`, I tried exporting the `google_calendar_wrapper` and it still raises the same error
- Both routers work independently of each other but nothing has helped so far and I have not found any solutions.

Here is the `calendar_manager_router` definition:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/health")
def health():
    """Api health endpoint."""
    return {"Api is up and running"}
```

Comment: So what is `calendar_manager_router`? Since that's what's giving you the error, it would probably be helpful to add that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastAPI's `include_router` accepts an `APIRouter`, but the object you imported in the main file, `calendar_manager_router`, is *another* FastAPI object. In your `google_calendar_wrapper`, you should be defining an `APIRouter` and that's what you import and include in your main app.

In `google_calendar_wrapper`, change it to:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()  # <---------

@router.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@router.get("/health")
def health():
    """Api health endpoint."""
    return {"Api is up and running"}
```

Notice the change to use `APIRouter`.

Then in your main app:

```
from test.main.app.google_calendar_wrapper import router as calendar_manager_router

...

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(
  calendar_manager_router, 
  prefix="/calendar_manager", 
  tags=["calendar_manager"]
)
```

See the FastAPI tutorials on [Bigger Applications - Multiple Files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/?h=#apirouter):

> You want to have the *path operations* related to your users separated from the rest of the code, to keep it organized.
>
> But it's still part of the same **FastAPI** application/web API (it's part of the same "Python Package").
>
> You can create the *path operations* for that module using `APIRouter`.
>
> ...
>
> You can think of `APIRouter` as a "mini FastAPI" class.